# Set NSLayoutConstrain between X and width in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Is it a way to set not programmatically but from Storyboard that view's X should be at 0.3 of the containing view's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is ,  you need to make it

```
leading = 0.3 of parentTrailing
```

[image]

OR

```
leading = 0.6 of parentCenterX
```

[image]